# .htaccess redirect all URLs to https excluding specific query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some rules that force any http URL to be rewritten with https
These rules should only apply for a specific HTTP Host (i.e. if the user is accessing the site through a specific subdomain name).

All working good, but now I want to disable the https redirect if the user is accessing a specific URL

e.g.
http://subdomain.domain.com/test/abc.html or http://subdomain.domain.com/test/123456.html

This is my code, but Apache seems to be ignoring my 2nd last line

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+talent/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Better to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` since `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: Seems to be working, but abc.html and 123456.html where just examples. There could potentially be anything in the /talent/ URL